# project compile error release 8 requires target 1.8 release

Tags: java, maven, fxml

I have an error `Error:java: javacTask: source release 8 requires target release 1.8`. I use 1.8 java, language level set to 8. The only thing I guess could be the reason is the line in the pom.xml file

```
         <configuration>
               <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
               <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
         </configuration>
```

here the line

```
 <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
```

is red and what to do with this I can't manage to get.

Comment: You need to set the compiler level to 1.8 explicitly in your pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the compiler version in Maven, you would have something that looks like this in your `pom.xml` file:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

3.3 is the latest Maven Compiler Plugin version.  I assumed it was needed for Java 8 support.

This is the [same as setting the -source and -target compiler options](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

Comment: Originally I had a Java 6 example here, but I decided to update it to Java 8 since that's more relevant.